# TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 4 inputs and I want when user filled the first input, focused on the second input.

```
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.textInput1 = React.createRef();
    this.textInput2 = React.createRef();
    this.textInput3 = React.createRef();
    this.textInput4 = React.createRef();

    this.onChangeInputText = this.onChangeInputText.bind(this)
```

---

```
  onChangeInputText(e){
    const index = e.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    console.log('index',index)
    if(index == 1)
      this.setState({'cardNumber1':e.target.value})
    if(index == 2)
      this.setState({'cardNumber2':e.target.value})
    if(index == 3)
      this.setState({'cardNumber3':e.target.value})
    if(index == 4)
      this.setState({'cardNumber4':e.target.value})

      if (e.target.value.length == 4) {
        this[`textInput${index + 1}`].current.focus()
      }
  }
```

my view:

```
  <input onChange={this.onChangeInputText} data-index={4} ref={this.textInput4} value={cardNumber4}  name="card4" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3 col-sm-3" style={{paddingLeft:'0px !important;'}} required="" autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]*" tabindex="4" maxLength="4" />
  <input onChange={this.onChangeInputText} data-index={3} ref={this.textInput3} value={cardNumber3}  name="card3" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3 col-sm-3" style={{paddingLeft:'0px !important;'}} required="" autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]*" tabindex="3" maxLength="4" />
  <input onChange={this.onChangeInputText} data-index={2} ref={this.textInput2}  value={cardNumber2}  name="card2" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3 col-sm-3" style={{paddingLeft:'0px !important;'}} required="" autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]*" tabindex="2" maxLength="4" />
 <input onChange={this.onChangeInputText} data-index={1} ref={this.textInput1} value={cardNumber1} name="card1" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3 col-sm-3" style={{paddingLeft:'0px !important;'}} required="" autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]*" tabindex="1" maxLength="4" />
```

but I got this message error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined
```

I can solve the problem with `if` statement:

```
  if (e.target.value.length == 4) {
   // this[`textInput${index + 1}`].current.focus()
   if(index == 1)
    this.textInput2.current.focus();
   if(index == 2)
    this.textInput3.current.focus();
   if(index == 3)
    this.textInput4.current.focus();

  }
```

Comment: don't you have forget the state in "if (e.target.value.length == 4) {
        this.STATE[`textInput${index + 1}`].current.focus()
      }" ?

Comment: What does `console.log('index',index)` log when your code fails?

Comment: I can solve the problem with `if` statement : `      if (e.target.value.length == 4) {
       // this[`textInput${index + 1}`].current.focus()
       if(index == 1)
        this.textInput2.current.focus();
       if(index == 2)
        this.textInput3.current.focus();
       if(index == 3)
        this.textInput4.current.focus();
       
      }`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (e.target.value.length == 4) {
    this[`textInput${index + 1}`].current.focus()
 }
```

so here `` this[`textInput${index + 1}`] `` this results in undefined in case your index is `4` and value.length is also `4`

so you end getting `this[textInpu5]`  which is undefined

Or if you don't parse your index into `number` you will have conditions like `this[textInput21]` or which will also be undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you increment the `index`, then for the fourth item, it will be trying to access `this.textInput5`, which doesn't exist - remove the `+ 1`:

```
this[`textInput${index}`].current.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

`index` happens to be a string. You're using it as string in your `if` comparisons. That works because `"1" == 1` is `true`. But when you're trying to do math, it's actually resulting in string concatenation. `"1" + 1` is `11`.

So, the line where the error occurs evaluates to `this.textInput11` which is undefined.

You can convert `index` to a number in the beginning itself, to prevent confusions. Like `const index = parseInt(e.currentTarget.dataset.index);`